# Periodically check if task has finished and discard task

Tags: c#, loops, task

My program is connecting to a server via TCP/IP. Basically I'm running a loop and which sends a status telegram on each iteration. Every once in a while my client receives a request from the server. These requests take up to 30 seconds to complete. Since don't want to stop sending my status telegram while these operation takes place. I am starting a new task for each request.

What is the proper way to initialize and dispose such one-use-tasks? Maybe there are better ways to accomplish this?

```
//...tcp init code...
Task<SomeData> handleDataTask = null;
while (true) 
{
    //...write status to networkstream...
    if (networkStream.DataAvailable)
    {
        //...
        handleDataTask = Task.Run(() => ExecuteRequest(Data));
        //...
    }

    if (handleDataTask != null) 
    {
        if (handleDataTask.isCompleted)
        {
            await handleDataTask;
            //.. do something with handleDataTask.Result...
            handleDataTask = null;
        }
    }
}
```

While this works, I am guessing there is a better way to dispose (or reuse?) the task.

Comment: [According to Stephen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/) (and he should know!) you *don't* usually need to dispose of `Task` objects.

Comment: Yes I've read his post but i don't think applies to my problem. Maybe dispose is the wrong word here. Iam talking about "nulling" the Task do avoid running the handling code again on the next loop iteration since handleDataTask.iscompleted is always true once the first task finishes.

Comment: In that case, what you're doing is fine.

Comment: Are you sure raw TCP is the right choice for you? There are a bunch of higher level protocols that take care of things like message framing, heartbeats, etc. Chances are existing protocols/libraries will be better tested and have less issues than anything developed in house.

Comment: I have a [video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIebvSMVr_dehKSoq6vuAW0BGEM6QnDlS) on writing an asynchronous TCP/IP server and client in C#. I second Jonas' recommendation, though: use a higher-level protocol if at all possible.